# Appropriate question?: Relevance of Josh Bloch's Effective Java

Tags: discussion, specific-question

*I want to ask the meta community about the following question. Please tell me if you believe it is on-topic for SO. I have yet to post this on Stack Overflow.*

I am looking to freshen up on Java skills and I've been looking around at resources to help me in that goal. One book that often comes to be mentioned is Josh Bloch's *Effective Java*. My concern is centered around that the book's last edition was release over 6 years ago, which is quite a long time in the world of software.

With that in mind, is the book still relevant to Java programming today? More specifically, can the book be used as a good resource for someone who is well versed in C# and .NET platform, but has more limited experience with the Java platform?

Comment: No. It would be closed as primarily-opinion based.

Comment: Not a good question for SO.

Comment: before anyone jumps in with beaten [toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773) suggestion: this would be inappropriate at Programmers either, as deadly mix of [education advice](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) and [off-site resource recommendation](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Comment: @gnat I do not intend to post this question anywhere if not well received here. That's why I asked here first. I knew it was borderline to begin with, and came to seek criticism to make it better, or to junk it.

Comment: @jdphenix I only commented because too many users at SO seem to be [still confused about what Programmers is for](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260) and attempt to send their garbage over there (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276812/any-tools-available-to-help-migrate-legacy-windows-6-1-mobile-app-to-windows-8-1#comment39392956_25276812) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090005/how-should-i-browse-a-huge-project-where-to-start#comment39040827_25090005))

Comment: @gnat I understand where you are coming from - :) I also know that SO (and SE sites in general) maintain higher quality than _anything_ else you can find on the internet where users can freely ask relevant questions and get answers to them, because the standards for questions are high. As they should be. I had my doubts about this one which I why I posted here first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would fit the *primarily opinion based* close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Basically, if your question includes the words "good resource," it will probably be closed in some way. Most good questions on Stack Overflow are based on *debugging* a *code sample*. Asking about anything that can not accurately be represented fully in a Stack Overflow question is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Okay - that's sounds reasonable enough as is. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509710/java-for-software-developers/ anyhow just now and I think it'll answer my question well enough anyhow. Thanks for the review.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your answer, but I'm leery of the second portion. I don't agree that "Most good questions on Stack Overflow are based on debugging a code sample." Perhaps it is empirically true, since asking an otherwise good question is rather difficult, but I don't think that good questions on Stack Overflow *must* do this. Seriously, do you want this to become a "debug my code for me" site? I don't. Those questions are sometimes appropriate, but this isn't HireAProgrammerForFakeMoney.com.

Comment: @CodyGray No, I was very careful to use *probably* and *most*. I'm just saying that if your question fits those guidelines, it will probably have less of a chance of being closed. I'm not saying there aren't exceptions either way.